# Extraction of tds from table using BeautifulSoup and arranging them in Pandas dataframe together with the table id

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have the following html code which I have extracted:

```html
<table id=table1>

  <thead>
    <tr class="table_columns">
      <th id="header1">
        "Column 1 Title"
      </th>
      <th id="header2">
        "Column 2 Title"
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="evenRow">
      <td headers="header1">firstrowcolumn1data</td>
      <td headers="header2">firstrowcolumn2data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oddRow">
      <td headers="header1">secondrowcolumn1data</td>
      <td headers="header2">secondrowcolumn2data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to extract the table data and id of the table (table1) then arrange them into a Pandas dataframe, similar to this:

| **id** | **table data** |
| --- | --- |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn2data |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn2data |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = []
for table in s.find_all('table'):
    for td in table.find_all('td'):
        data.append((table.get('id'), td.text))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'table data'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       id            table data
0  table1   firstrowcolumn1data
1  table1   firstrowcolumn2data
2  table1  secondrowcolumn1data
3  table1  secondrowcolumn2data
```

Comment: Hi @user17242583. I realised that the solution produces duplicates. One set has the actual id of the table, while the other set has "None" as the id. I checked the html code I crawled and couldn't find any duplicate of the table. Would there be any reason for this?

Comment: Not sure about that, @Tipo33. Why don't you open a new question about this, since it's difficult to discuss in the comments.