# Extraction of date from first two columns of a table using BeautifulSoup and arranging them in Pandas dataframe without duplicates

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

This is a follow-up question to my earlier question, [Extraction of tds from table using BeautifulSoup and arranging them in Pandas dataframe together with the table id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369738/extraction-of-tds-from-table-using-beautifulsoup-and-arranging-them-in-pandas-da)

I had encountered unusual behaviour in the solution:

1. Empty row entries due to the existence of a third column, which I had regrettably neglected from mention in my above-mentioned question
2. the appearance of duplicate records in the Pandas dataframe as was created in my above-mentioned question

I have the following html code which I have extracted:

```html
<table id=table1>

  <thead>
    <tr class="table_columns">
      <th id="header1">
        "Column 1 Title"
      </th>
      <th id="header2">
        "Column 2 Title"
      </th>
      <th id="header3">
        <span></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="evenRow">
      <td headers="_header1">firstrowcolumn1data</td>
      <td headers="_header2">firstrowcolumn2data</td>
      <td headers="_header3">
        <a>
          <img src="image1">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oddRow">
      <td headers="_header1">secondrowcolumn1data</td>
      <td headers="_header2">secondrowcolumn2data</td>
      <td headers="_header3">
        <a>
          <img src="image1">
        </a>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to extract the table data and id of the table (table1) then arrange them into a Pandas dataframe, similar to this:

| **id** | **table data** |
| --- | --- |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn2data |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn2data |

I had implemented the following solution as given in response to my previous question:

```
data = []
for table in s.find_all('table'):
    for td in table.find_all('td'):
        data.append((table.get('id'), td.text))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'table data'])
```

However, my output is as follows:

| **id** | **table data** |
| --- | --- |
| None | firstrowcolumn1data |
| None | firstrowcolumn2data |
| None |  |
| None | secondrowcolumn1data |
| None | secondrowcolumn2data |
| None |  |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | firstrowcolumn2data |
| table1 |  |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn1data |
| table1 | secondrowcolumn2data |
| table1 |  |

Please advise.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the same bad dataframe. The datframe I get by running your code looks just like your expected one, there are a few rows that have `\n\n\n\n\n` as the content.

Comment: are you sure you provided the same HTML that you're using?

Comment: @user17242583 I can't present the entire code here as it is far too complex. Given the other challenges I am facing, I am willing to live with the duplicates that have "None" as their id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.assign(**{'table data': df['table data'].str.replace(r'^\s+$', '', regex=True)}).replace({None:np.nan,'':np.nan,'None':np.nan}).dropna()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        id            table-data
6   table1  firstrowcolumn1data 
7   table1  firstrowcolumn2data 
9   table1  secondrowcolumn1data
10  table1  secondrowcolumn2data
```